# Mountain Lion no login field after booting

Tags: startup, login

My 2012 MBA (no bootcamp) just shows a bare splash screen without user avatar nor password field after booting. Now I've seen this problem twice, I can type my password and then hit return on keyboard to login, but the login field never shows.

What's the problem here? Any fixes?

Comment: Do you have an external display plugged in or are you otherwise using the Thunderbolt port?

Comment: @jaume No, but you've given me a hint. I have installed Air Display, I think it may be the reason, I'll remove it and see whether it'll happen again. Thanks!

Comment: Good, try it and report back.

Comment: @jaume I can now confirm it is caused by Air Display, after un-istalled it this never happens again. Would you please write an answer so that I can close this question?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, it's great you could isolate the cause. I added an answer as you requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that OS X detects 2 monitors and thinks that the secondary monitor is the main one.

This can happen with a monitor connected to the Thunderbolt port or in your case, as you state in a comment above, using virtual monitor software [Air Display](http://avatron.com/apps/air-display).

Apparently, Air Display didn't detect that the built-in MacBook Air monitor was active, so it sent the video signal over WiFi to a peer Air Display device.

As a consequence you only saw the bare splash screen.